# how save multiple row of data with single query in cake php?

Tags: cakephp

How make this Query in cake php? I used `$this->saveAll(myData);`. But this method used 5 query to insert this data.
I want insert this data with one query.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `value1`, `value2`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1,),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 2, 2),
(4, 2, 3),
(5, 3, 3),
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: i want save this with one mysql query

Comment: Maybe build your own query? I was unaware that saveMany and saveAll used multiple queries http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [`DboSource::insertMulti()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-DboSource.html#_insertMulti).

```
$data = array(
  'Model' => array(
    'field' => 'value',
    'other' => 'another value'
  )
);
$ds = $this->Model->getDatasource();
$ds->insertMuli($this->Model->table, array_keys($data['Model']), $data['Model']);
```

Comment: Hey Harris, I think this function also fire multiple insert query instead of just one, isn't it?

Comment: @Parixit not according to the code itself :) If you look at insertMulit it just does a single INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
$this->Model->saveMany($data);
```

data should be in this format :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Model] => Array
            (
                [field] => value
                [field] => value
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Model] => Array
            (
                [field_1] => value
                [field_2] => value
            )

    )
```

)